# GOST 3411 Algorithm using Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, hmac, digest

Am using GOST algorithm to create a hash based on key and input using Bouncy castle libs. Below code generates Hash that doesn't match with the one generated through online tools such as http://beautifytools.com/hmac-generator.php

```
    HMac gMac= new HMac(new GOST3411Digest());

    byte[] key = "keyphrase".getBytes();
    byte[] input = "macinput".getBytes();

    gMac.init(new KeyParameter(key));

    gMac.update(input, 0, input.length);
    byte[] mac = new byte[gMac.getMacSize()];

    gMac.doFinal(mac, 0);
    BigInteger in = new BigInteger(1, mac);
    System.out.println(in.toString(16));
```

When this works, Need to use inside Mulesoft to call API which validates the Hash and gives authentication. Basically, The encyption is for generation of authentication token.

Have been referring to stackoverflow for a long time but never had an opportunity to post any questions. This is my first :)

Thanks,
Sudeep

Comment: What is it that you expect?

Answer (score 0):

GOST3411 algorithm has several SBox options, so try using different upon initialization. I had some luck with "D-Test" SBox, it matches with most if not all online tools. You can initialize different SBox like this:

```
HMac mac = new HMac(new GOST3411Digest(GOST28147Engine.getSBox("D-Test")));
```