# Bouncycastle GOST 34.311 hash differ from test examples differ

Tags: hash, bouncycastle, java-security, gost3411

could you, please, help with [bouncycastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) for hash function [GOST 34.311](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOST_(hash_function)). Somehow results are diffferent from test vector.
Wiki says:
"*GOST("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog") =
77b7fa410c9ac58a25f49bca7d0468c9296529315eaca76bd1a10f376d1f4294*"

when using Digest Gost 34.11:

```
var testString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
var result = (new GOST3411.Digest()).digest(testString.getBytes());
var resHex2 = new BigInteger(1, result).toString(16);
assertEquals("77b7fa410c9ac58a25f49bca7d0468c9296529315eaca76bd1a10f376d1f4294", resHex2.toUpperCase());
```

got:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :77b7fa410c9ac58a25f49bca7d0468c9296529315eaca76bd1a10f376d1f4294
Actual   :9004294A361A508C586FE53D1F1B02746765E71B765472786E4770D565830A76
```

with 2012 version:

```
var testString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
var result = (new GOST3411.Digest2012_256()).digest(testString.getBytes());
var resHex2 = new BigInteger(1, result).toString(16);
assertEquals("77b7fa410c9ac58a25f49bca7d0468c9296529315eaca76bd1a10f376d1f4294", resHex2.toUpperCase());
```

got :

```
AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :77b7fa410c9ac58a25f49bca7d0468c9296529315eaca76bd1a10f376d1f4294
Actual   :3E7DEA7F2384B6C5A3D0E24AAA29C05E89DDD762145030EC22C71A6DB8B2C1F4
```

Does BouncyCastle support origin GOST 34.311 - 95? What is correct way to calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

BC is using the `GOST R 34.11-2012` ([streebog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streebog)) version of the standard

```
$ rhash -G -m "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
3e7dea7f2384b6c5a3d0e24aaa29c05e89ddd762145030ec22c71a6db8b2c1f4  (message)
```

The wikipedia samples are for the deprecated `GOST R 34.11-94` version

```
$ rhash --gost94 -m "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
77b7fa410c9ac58a25f49bca7d0468c9296529315eaca76bd1a10f376d1f4294  (message)
```

If you actually want the old one, you should probably ask for plain `GOST3411Digest` instead of `GOST3411.Digest2012_256` which is the new one.

Comment: thanks, thus result for (new GOST3411.Digest()).digest(...)  is also different fom wiki test vector...

Comment: @Bogdan maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47588919/14215102